# unable to use speech recognition in python

Tags: python, speech-recognition

I am trying to make a virtual assistant for which I need the speech recognition module but it's showing a timeout error I tried to increase the timeout manually to 5 seconds yet the issue prevails.

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyaudio 
import sounddevice as sd
a = sd.query_devices()
print (a)
r = sr.Recognizer()

with sr.Microphone(device_index=2) as source:
    print('say....')
    audio = r.listen(source)
    voice_data = r.recognize_google(audio)
    print(voice_data)
```

The error shown is as follows

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/vipulvasant/Desktop/my codes/ABP/main.py", line 10, in <module>
    audio = r.listen(source)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/speech_recognition/_init_.py", line 618, in listen
    raise WaitTimeoutError("listening timed out while waiting for phrase to start")
speech_recognition.WaitTimeoutError: listening timed out while waiting for phrase to start
```

this is the first step towards my dream of making my own virtual assistant

Answer (score 0):

Adding a simple a `while True:` statement should fix the issue.
As i ran into the same issue and this was my solution.

```py
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyaudio 
import sounddevice as sd
a = sd.query_devices()
print (a)
r = sr.Recognizer()

while True:
    with sr.Microphone(device_index=2) as source:
        print('say....')
        audio = r.listen(source)
        voice_data = r.recognize_google(audio)
        print(voice_data)
```

Comment: Hey man still running in the same error

Comment: I also changed the r.listen argument to r.record it doesn't give an error however it does not process further

Answer (score 0):

Here try this. I don't know if this is what you are asking for but I hope it helps:

```
import speech_recognition
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("Speak:")
    audio = r.listen(source)
voice_data = r.recognize_google(audio)
print(voice_data)
```